# Triangles with a given outer Soddy circle of the Malfatti circles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, triangles

I did a JavaScript interactive picture of the Malfatti circles of a triangle. The user can drag the vertices of the triangle and the Malfatti circles are updated accordingly.

Now, I would like to restrict the transformations of the original triangle in order that they preserve the outer Soddy circle of the Malfatti circles (the goal is to do an interactive Apollonian gasket with a fixed exterior circle).

In other words, let's say that the outer Soddy circle of the Malfatti circles of a triangle is the *Soddy-Malfatti circle* of this triangle; what are all the triangles which have a given Soddy-Malfatti circle ?

---

## EDIT

[Here](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/frames/paperjs_Malfatti.html) is the interactive picture (click and drag). How to move the triangle in such a way that the outer circle remains fixed?

Comment: This is a suggestion on how to compute the required (two parameter) family of triangles which have a given $C$ as Soddy-Malfatti circle (a comment since I haven‘t done the computations).  Wlog $C$ is the unit circle with centre at the origin of a coordinate plane.  Each triangle is directly similar to one of the form $ABC$ with $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(p,q)$. We now compute the centre  $M(p,q)$ and radius $r(p,q)$ of its Soddy-Malfatti circle. A translation by $–M(p,q)$ and dilation by $\frac 1 {r(p,q)}$ maps $ABC$ into a suitable triangle.  Doing this for each $p$ and $q$ suffices.

Comment: @user131781 Thank you, this works! See the [animation](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MindlessSafeGalapagospenguin-size_restricted.gif) :-)

Comment: The [new JS picture](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/frames/paperjs_Malfatti2.html). The two sliders give the values of $p$ and $q$. @user131781 Maybe you can convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: nice graphics. will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the poster, I am expanding my comment to an answer.  We are given a circle $\cal C$ which we take to be the unit one with centre at the origin of the coordinate plane.  Now if $PQR$ is a triangle in the plane, there is a unique triangle $ABC$ with $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(p,q)$ to which it is directly similar.  (This is a common ploy in triangle geometry which seems to have been discovered and forgotten several times but goes back at least to Euler).  We compute the Soddy-Malfatti circle of $ABC$
and denote its centre by $M(p,q)$, its radius by $r(p,q)$.  If we translate the original triangle by $-M(p,q)$, then dilate it by $\frac 1 {r(p,q)}$, we obtain one with $\cal C$ as Soddy-Malfatti circle.  Repeating this for all values of $p$ and $q$ gives a two parameter family of triangles with the required properties.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the [Apollonian gasket](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/frames/paperjs_MalfattiApollonius.html).

Comment: It has just occurred to me that I missed one degree of freedom—one actually gets a three parameter family (as one would expect—the family of triangles has dimension 6 and one has three restraints, radius and centre of the S-M circle).  The missing dimension can be restored by rotating  about the centre of the S-M circle.  You see this in your graphics—all the triangle bases are horizontal.

Comment: I added a degree of freedom to $B$ like this: $B=(1,y)$. [Graphics](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/frames/paperjs_Malfatti3.html), with $y$ corresponding to the third slider. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes— looks great. you now see the triangles rotating.  By the way, the same method could be used with respect to other circles associated with a triangle—the nine point circle springs as first to mind (circum- in- and ex-circles are probably not too interesting), but there are many others.